# How to solve imagettftext not change image

Tags: php, imagettftext

I don't know why after the first imagettftext bring output images, I can't made another image, I always found my first imagettftext.
My code here

```
imagettftext($im,  $ukuran, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
imagepng($im, $save);
imagedestroy($im);
```

However I just found my first image from imagettftext process, What's wrong? and is it a cache?